# Oracle Sql : create column/table with a for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create a table with a column that will hold integer values from 1 to 2000.

Then I want insert records into the table with each value (1,2,3,...,2000).

I tried using a for loop to do so, but I don't succeed.

Can someone help me ?'

Thanks

Comment: Your intentions are not quite clear. And where are all your attempts? Code please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle 11g - FOR loop that inserts only weekdays into a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587501/oracle-11g-for-loop-that-inserts-only-weekdays-into-a-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable AS
SELECT level AS columnname FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2000;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49c0d/1